# How to get the list of commands entered in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am fairly new to Powershell and I am practising using different commands.I haven't remembered all the commands.
Is there any way to get the list of all the commands that has entered?

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a command that gives you the list of commands entered during the current session.

Use below command :

> Get-History

Comment: Yes it's worked, thank you for your help @Nilesh Shinde

Comment: Happy to help you @shubh_jadha